# Can not insert nodes in an AVL Tree properly

Tags: c++, algorithm, data-structures, binary-tree, avl-tree

Can someone please help me with AVL Trees, I think I'm doing it wrong when computing the new balance in rotationRightLeft function. I'm not allowed to use max function so I'm trying this method..

```
template <class T>
void ArbreAVL<T>::insert(const T & e) {
    bool Issuccess = insert(racine, e);
    std::cout << e << " : "<< Issuccess << std::endl;
    std::cout.flush();
}

template <class T>
bool ArbreAVL<T>::insert(Node*& node, const T & e) {
    if(node== nullptr){
        node= new Node(e);
        return true;
    }
    if(e < node->content){
        if(insert(node->left, e)){
            node->balance++;
            
            if(node->balance== 0)
                return false;
            if(node->balance == 1)
                return true;
            assert(node->balance == 2);
            if(node->left->balance== -1)
                rotationRightLeft(node->left);
            rotationLeftRight(node);
        }
        return false;    
    }else if(e > node->content){
        if(insert(node->right, e)){
            node->balance++;
            
            if(node->balance == 0)
                return false;
            if(node->balance == -1)
                return true;
            assert(node->balance == -2);
            if(node->right->balance== 1)
                rotationLeftRight(node->right);
            rotationRightLeft(node);
        }
        return false;
    }else{
        node->content= e;
        return false;
    }
}
```

```
template <class T>
void ArbreAVL<T>::rotationRightLeft(Node*& rootChildTree) {
    Node* a = rootChildTree->right;
    Node* b = rootChildTree;
    int ea = a->balance;
    int eb = b->balance;
    
    int eap = - (eb < 0 ? eb : 0) - 1 + ea;
    int ebp = eb + (eap > 0 ? eap : 0) - 1;
    
    a->balance= eap;
    b->balance= ebp;
    b->right= a->left;
    a->left= b;
    rootChildTree= a;
}
```

I tested the insert method and here's the output. Can someone please tell me what's wrong with the balance computation. It seems to be working in the rotationLeftRight method since the node with the element 2 is inserted to the left of the node with element 4 (see the output image)

Computation I used in rotationLeftRight function :

```
int ebp = - (ea > 0 ? ea : 0) - 1 + eb;
int eap = ea + (ebp < 0 ? ebp : 0) - 1;
```

```
#include <iostream>
#include "arbreavl.h"

int main() {
    std::cout << "Test #1" << std::endl;
    int error= 0;
    ArbreAVL<int> A;
    A.insert(4);
    A.insert(2);
    A.insert(6);
    A.insert(1);
    A.insert(3);
    A.insert(5);
    A.insert(7);
    A.print();
    std::cout << A.size() << std::endl;
    if(A.size() != 7) {
        std::cerr << "ERROR- I" << std::endl;
        error++;
    }
    if(error == 0)
        std::cout << "\t==> OK"<< std::endl;
    return error;
}
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rw2bg.png)

Comment: What have you done to debug the situation? Did you use a debugger? Did you inspect variables? Or are you asking that we debug your code for you?

Comment: I have absolutely no intention to be mean. I was just trying to find out what you had done to debug the situation, since we expect a question to "show research effort" (quoted from the tooltip that hangs over the downvote button).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Learning algorithms on the example of AVL trees is an interesting task.

Talking about existing code:
In your method `insert(Node*& node, const T& e)` there is an error in `if`: `if(condition){} else if(the same condition)`. Also, the very operations that take place in the bodies of conditions look like failed copying from another `if` (`++` instead of `--`, etc.).

Regarding the turnover functions, as far as I understand, they do not work at all. To turn, you have to change the value of the root and its children in a way, that will make the maximum death of left and right child equal(or rather their difference shouldn't be greater than 1). Simply changing the value of the balance will not work. More details about how to balance an AVL tree are described [here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44583117/can-this-binary-tree-be-balanced) or [on en.wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree#Simple_rotation).

Generally, your right turn should follow the next algorithm:

1. get your turn point(`root`), left son(`left`), right son(`right`) and right son of the `left`(`grandson`)
2. you make your `left` your new `root`
3. your old `root` become your new `right`(so it is now right son of old `left`)
4. your old `grandson` becomes new left child of your old `root`(so new left child of new right child of root)
5. chill

In code it will be something similar to this

```cpp
void turnRight(Node*& root, Node* left, Node* right, Node* grandson)
{
    Node* old_root = root;
    root = left;
    left->right = old_root;
    old_root->left = grandson
}
turnRight(root, root->left, root->right, root->left->right);
```